# problem with getting correct pid in tcsh shell

Tags: windows, shell, unix, pid, tcsh

I'm trying to get the pid of a process I run in tcsh.
I'm doing it like this:

```
my_program.exe &
echo "$!"
```

But instead of getting the pid of the process I've just run, I'm getting the pid of the csh.exe itself.

How can I fix it and do it correctly?

Thank you

Comment: .exe suffixes? Are you using a Windows port of tcsh?

Comment: yes exe suffix. using tcsh

Comment: But the question is tagged with linux? It works as expected for me on Linux anyway; you can also get the PID from `jobs -l`.